# Can I use both introspection server and local check for authorize token? Spring Boot - Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I want to

1. introspect JWT token on remote server
2. and then check locally if scope/aud/iss/exp are correct

How can this be done most easily in Spring Boot?

As I understand first case is something similar to opauqeToken functionality (but I have normal JWT) and second case is more like using jwt

> Spring Security only supports JWTs or Opaque Tokens, not both at the same time.

If I use opaqueToken, then validation on remote server is done without any effort (even if that's JWT)

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .mvcMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_" + scope)
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                    .opaqueToken(opaque -> opaque
                            .introspectionUri(this.introspectionUri)
                            .introspectionClientCredentials(this.clientId, this.clientSecret)
                    ));
    return http.build();
```

I have scope verified. Now I want to check `iss`, `aud`, `exp`. Is that doable with `opaqueToken`?

Or should I use `jwt` auth instead?

IMHO `opaqueToken` can be JWT, so now the question is how to verify and inspect it locally after remote introspection?

It's kind of hybrid of two different approaches, but hopefully you know the simple way how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have my answer. I created my own introspector which is implementing `OpaqueTokenIntrospector`

```
public class JwtOpaqueTokenIntrospector implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {

    private OpaqueTokenIntrospector delegate =
            new NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector(
                    "introspect-url",
                    "client-id",
                    "client-secret"
            );

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspect(String token) {
        OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspected = this.delegate.introspect(token);
        // SOME LOGIC
    }
}
```

and I added it as a @Bean

```
    @Bean
    public OpaqueTokenIntrospector tokenIntrospector() {
        return new JwtOpaqueTokenIntrospector();
    }
```